# Angular js - How to extract partial data from json file located in my server for a detail view passing a parameter?

Tags: angularjs, json, http, detailsview

I am a newbie in Angular. I suppose it's an easy question. I have a json file which contains different objects hosted in my server. I got display a list with each object. Now, when I click on each list item (object), I want to show the details of each one in a detail view (different from the list view). I know how to redirect to this detail view using a parameter (id), but I don't know how to render the details of that specific object. 
Here I show my code:

data.json

```
[
{
"id": "1",
"name": "james", 
"age": "20",
"city": "NY"
},
{
"id": "2",
"name": "allan", 
"age": "21",
"city": "London"
},
{
"id": "3",
"name": "thomas", 
"age": "22",
"city": "Belfast"
}
]
```

app.js

```
angular.module("myApp", ["controllers", "services", "directives", "ngRoute"]);
angular.module("myApp").config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'templates/home.html',
        controller  : 'HomeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/list', {
        templateUrl : 'templates/list.html',
        controller  : 'ListCtrl'
    })
    .when('/list/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/item.html',
        controller: 'ItemCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'}); 
});
```

controllers.js

```
...
.controller('ListCtrl',function($scope, MyService) {
$scope.list = {};
MyService.getData()
    .then( function(result) {                                  
            $scope.list=result.data;
            })
    .catch( function(error) { 
            console.log('There is an error.', error); 
            }); 
})
.controller('ItemCtrl',function($scope, $routeParams, MyService, $location) {
var id = $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
$scope.item = {};
MyService.getData()
    .then( function(result) { 
            $scope.item=result.data;
                if(id) {
                    return result.data[id]
                }
            })
    .catch( function(error) { 
            console.log('There is an error.', error); 
            });   
})
```

service.js

```
...
.factory('MyService', function($http) {     
return  { getData: getData };
function getData() {
    return $http.get('data.json'); 
}
})
```

item.html

```
<div ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    <p>{{item.city}}</p>
</div>
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the list of object with your service and you can save them on a variable inside the service so you do not make a call to the service (to get the json file) every time unless you need to get the latest data every-time.

**If you have issues with the code below check the plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/1k3RhxIWnsdY7rPViRhK?p=preview**

In your service you can do this

```
...
.factory('MyService', function($http, $q, $filter) {     

    var itemList = [];
    var self = {};

    self.getList = getList;
    self.getItem = getItem;

    return self;

    function getList(){
        var defer = $q.defer();

        $http.get('data.json').then(function(response){
            itemList = response.data;
            defer.resolve(itemList); // you can do data manipulation here if you need to
        },function(error){
           defer.reject(error); //you can customize your error
        });

        return defer.promise;
    }

    function getItem(itemId){
       if(itemList){
           var found = $filter('filter')(itemList, {id:itemId}, true);

           return found[0]; //the [0] is to get the first item since found is an array
       }
    }
})
```

You can load the data (items) in the list controller before the controller loads in your route.  Make sure you inject "items" in your controller.

```
angular.module("myApp").config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/list', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
        controller: 'ListCtrl',
        resolve: {
            items: function(MyService){
                MyService.getList().then(function(response){
                  return response
                });
            }
        }
    })
  .
  ...Other Routes Here...
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
```

});

Now in your item controller you can do this

```
.controller('ItemCtrl',function($scope, $routeParams, MyService) {
    var id = $routeParams.id;

    $scope.item = MyService.getItem(id);

})
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, btinoco. Unfortunately, an error appeared: There is an error. TypeError: defer.resolve is not a function(…) And the items list doesn't appear too. Definitely, a JSBin could be helpful.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Here it is the plunkr for you to see: https://plnkr.co/edit/1k3RhxIWnsdY7rPViRhK?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much @btinoco. I'll try it when I get home.

Comment: cool man...hey if my answer helped you please mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @btinoco. Definitely, it's useful. I need to adapt it a little more to my current code. It's not working yet. These days I'll try to do it (I'm truly busy this week). Anyway, your answer has been really useful. Hope I can ask you any little doubt -in case I get stacked.

Comment: Sure thing. Let me know.